# How can I call and get back the results of an SP from another Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have this stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_get_correct_responses]       
    @QuestionUId    UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
AS
BEGIN
        ...

    -- This is the last part of the SP. I need to use the output 
    -- value of @AnswerGridCorrect in the calling SP
    SELECT  @AnswerGridCorrect = Correct
    FROM    Concatenated
    WHERE   RowNumber = ColumnCount

END
```

How can I call the stored procedure from another stored procedure, pass it the @QuestionUId parameter and put the returned variable @AnswerGridCorrect into a variable declared in the calling procedure?

Update: Here's the proposed answer:

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_get_correct_responses]       
    @QuestionUId    UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
    @output VARCHAR(20) output
AS
BEGIN

select @QuestionUId

    DECLARE @AnswerGridCorrect VARCHAR(20)
    DECLARE @QuestionId int;

    SELECT @QuestionId = QuestionId
    FROM dbo.Question 
    Where QuestionUId = @QuestionUId;

    Select @questionId;

    WITH Partitioned AS (
        SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY QuestionId ORDER BY AnswerId ASC) AS RowNumber,
                COUNT(1) OVER (PARTITION BY QuestionId) AS ColumnCount,
                CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), Correct) AS Correct
        FROM    dbo.Answer
        WHERE   [QuestionId] = @QuestionId
    ),
    Concatenated AS (
        SELECT RowNumber, ColumnCount, Correct FROM Partitioned WHERE RowNumber = 1 
        UNION ALL   
        SELECT      P.RowNumber,
                    P.ColumnCount,
                    C.Correct + P.Correct AS Correct
        FROM        Partitioned P
        INNER JOIN  Concatenated C
        ON          P.RowNumber = C.RowNumber + 1
    )

    SET @output = (SELECT  Correct
                   FROM    Concatenated
                   WHERE   RowNumber = ColumnCount)
    RETURN

END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have a temp table in the other stored procedure and populate it with the results of this one:

```
INSERT INTO #table
Exec sp_get_correct_responses @QuestionUId
```

The other way would be to modify `sp_get_correct_responses` to produce an output as you are expecting only one value.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_get_correct_responses]       
    @QuestionUId    UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
    @output VARCHAR(20) output
AS
BEGIN
        ...

    -- This is the last part of the SP. I need to use the output 
    -- value of @AnswerGridCorrect in the calling SP
    SELECT @output = Correct
    FROM    Concatenated
    WHERE   RowNumber = ColumnCount
    RETURN

END
```

And in your other SP:

```
DECLARE @output VARCHAR(20)
EXEC sp_get_correct_responses
  @QuestionUId,
  @output output

SELECT @output
```

Comment: This gives me a message saying "incorrect syntax near SET"

Comment: Thanks. I have added the completed solution that gives me a syntax error on SET to my answer. Do you have any idea what might be wrong?

Comment: Check the sp definition, i have added another parameter and set it as output. I do not have only QuestionUId in the declaration, but also output.

Comment: @UpendraChaudhari I changed it as you suggested, only because it is clearer, but that is not OPs issue. His issue is that he has not changed the header of the sp definition as i suggested to output the parameter. So his error is that output variable is not declared.

Comment: Sorry I just changed the header now but I am still getting an error on SET SQL46010 :: Incorrect syntax near SET.

Comment: You should probably change it to `SELECT @output = Correct
    FROM    Concatenated
    WHERE   RowNumber = ColumnCount` as suggested by UpendraChaudhari

Answer (score 0):

You can make one table variable in parent SP and insert result of child SP in that like below :

```
DECLARE @TempTable TABLE(AnswerGridCorrect INT)
INSERT INTO @TempTable 
EXEC [dbo].[sp_get_correct_responses] @QuestionUId
```